# Creating a geospatial query to find two users within each other's radius

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, aggregation-framework

I am creating a matching system based on user proximity. The basic idea is I have  user A at point A and user B at another point B. Both users have search filters that determine how far a user can be to make a match. This distance is in Kilometers. [image: A crude depiction]

Anyways would it be possible to do this in a single vanilla query (without using an aggregate query)? Here is the query I have so far

```
var loc = userA.location;
var rad = userA.radius;

{$near : {
        $geometry : {
            type : "Point",
            coordinates : loc
        },
        $maxDistance : rad
    }
}
```

How do I account for user's B preference though?

I was planning to store a geometry that was basically their circle of preference and then see if userA was within that circle, but this just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the `radius` property stored on each user, so that is a good thing, and not only for a `$maxDistance` option, but also as a check to see if the distance between users is "less than" the `radius` attribute.

What you now basically need is a way to "see" that distance and "compare". For this you use the aggregation framework and [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/):

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": userA.location
        },
        "spherical": true,
        "maxDistance": userA.radius,
        "distanceField": "distance"
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$lt": [ "$distance", "$radius" ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
 ])
```

So what this does it executes the same sort of `$near` result along with the `"maxDistance"` constraint, but actually returns an additional property in the named `"distanceField"` representing the actual distance between found 'users'. The `"spherical"` option is required when the index is `"2dsphere"`.

As an aggregation "pipeline", this allows another operation to act on the output. The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage makes a "logical comparison" of the existing `"radius"` data and the generated `"distance"` field, to see if that distance is "less than" the stored radius data.

Only when that condition is `true` is the document returned via `$$KEEP`, otherwise the distance is larger than the users radius as the document is removed from results via `$$PRUNE`.

That's how you make a comparison that respects the `radius` on the user data for returning results.